# Will a server that has a different public port affect mysql?

Tags: mysql, laravel, port

I have a server that I do not own it's a server from a third party group and it is assigned on a different public ip port like 0.0.0.0:8080 and now when I migrate using laravels migration command it returns a connection timed out. Will this different public port affect the connection on mysql? as the db_host in my .env file is specified as 0.0.0.0 without the port 8080.

Comment: Have you tried adding the port to the .env config settings?

Comment: Is this the MySQL server that has a different port, or the HTTP/HTTPS part?

Comment: check your mysql server is up and running or not, after that if mysql server is not on the same node as your php server, try to check the connection between these two.

Comment: @tadman it's the HTTP/HTTPS part brother.

Comment: @mhndev when I type service mysql status it says active (running)

Comment: @Adam yes the port in my .env file is 3306 whenever I use nmap with my servers ip it doesn't show 3306 as open it only shows 80 and 53

Comment: Sorry for the later reply guys I was sick yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made the migration worked. It's very weird as I am a noob at servers and networks it might be normal for you guys. But the problem was when I nmap the ip of the server it does not show 3306 as an open port but when I nmap localhost it shows 3306 as open port what I did basically is changed the .env file db_host to localhost and migration started and succeeded. I'm guessing this is a network issue maybe? but the problem now would be how would can I connect remotely from mysql workbench.

Comment: From what you described in your question, I'd say the reason was that `0.0.0.0` is no actual IP and `.env` requires an IP to connect to. `0.0.0.0` is normally used to tell a server that it should listen on any interface. E.g. if you have two interfaces, `127.0.0.1` for `localhost` and let's say `192.168.1.15` for the local network, it will listen on both interfaces. But when you want to connect to a server, you need to use a specific IP address like `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.1.15` (or an alias like `localhost` which is defined in the `hosts` file).

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a special IP meaning "all" when used for binding or the "listen" configuration parameter. It's a wildcard IP that you can't connect to. You must use actual IPs your system has configured.